# NullPointer In Recursive Method (Getting General Tree Path)

Tags: java

I'm working on a program where I've made a rough outline of a General Tree with a file system. I have a class called `File` and I have 2 classes that extend File which are `Directory` and `TextFile`. In my `FileSystem` class I have a variable that stores the root. I'm pretty sure I'm getting the NullPointerException because of how I made my `FileSystem` class, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is my File class:

```
public abstract class File {
private String name;
private Directory parent;

public File(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Directory getParent() {
    return parent;
}

String getName() {
    return name;
}

void setParent(Directory parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

String getPath() {
    return getPath(this);
}

String getPath(File f) {
    if (f == FileSystem.getRoot()) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return getPath(f.parent) + "/" + f.name;
    }
}

}
```

Here is my Directory class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Directory extends File {
private ArrayList<File> children = new ArrayList<File>();

Directory(String name){
    super(name);
}

void addChild(File f){
    setParent(this);
    children.add(f);
}

ArrayList<File> getChildren(){
    return children;
}
}
```

Here is my FileSystem class:

```
public class FileSystem {
static Directory root;

//Constructor
public FileSystem(){

}

//Constructor with parameters
public FileSystem(Directory root){
    this.root = root;
}

public static File getRoot(){
    return root;
}
}
```

And here is what I try doing in my main method:

```
//Creating root directory
    Directory root = new Directory("/");

    //Creating FileSystem user will add and remove directories/text files from
    FileSystem tree = new FileSystem(root);

    Directory a = new Directory("a");
    Directory b = new Directory("b");
    Directory c = new Directory("c");

    root.addChild(a);
    a.addChild(b);
    b.addChild(c);

    c.getPath();
```

Any help with figuring out how to trace my path would be greatly appreciated. I wanted it to print out this: `/a/b/c`

Comment: @BenKnoble If I don't do that I can't make it a recursive method. Unless I did something like `Directory rent = this.parent;` and then `rent.getPath()` before I returned in my `else` statement. But I've already tried something like that and it either gave me a `StackOverFlowException` or `NullPointerException`

Comment: I misread your code structure. My bad.

Comment: @BenKnoble that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem can be in this method:

```
void addChild(File f){
   setParent(this); //seting parent for directory not for file which is passed
   children.add(f);
}
```

try change to:

```
f.setParent(this)
```

Comment: @gaueeI no longer have any errors, but my result is never printed. What could be causing this?

Comment: Did You put the result of c.getPath() into sout?

Comment: What do you mean the result into sout? (I apologize for double posting). EDIT: I put it in a `System.out.println(c.getPath());` and it worked. I didn't think I needed to do that because I returned a String?

Comment: This method c.getPath returns simple String. This string must to put to system output. __sout__ is shortcut from Intellij which will be replace with System.out.println(...);
So try to add this line:
System.out.println(c.getPath());

Comment: Exactly, String is only an object. All what You need to print should be put into sout. For some custom objects You additionally need to override method toString() to make sure that something will be printed instead of ClassName with hashCode.
You're welcome!